# Spark Multinode Cluster: Unable to open cluster info in web UI

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-zookeeper, bigdata

I have created a multinode cluster in SPARK. I have added the IP address of both machines into `/etc/hosts` file on both machines. The commands are working fine, like `start-master.sh` and `start-slave.sh`.

Even zookeeper is showing who is the leader and who is the follower in the terminal, when running the command `zkServer.sh status` command. But when I am going to web UI using `"slave1:8080"` it is showing page not found.

Note- slave1 and slave2 are machine names.

What can be the issue with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can paste your configuration files that would be great !

Comment: you need to open web UI in Master Node "MasterIP:8080" slaves doesnt have WebUI